# How to auto restart node server when update mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to restart auto node server when i run query of mongodb. I used nodemon but It's only works when i'm changing in codes.

Comment: First of all, why do you wanna restart node server after querying?

Comment: I want to fetch data from mongodb when query is update.

Comment: Why would this require a "restart"? It seems to me that your "question" is a classic case of "what you think happens" instead of actually presenting the use case of what you really need to do. Believe me though that "restarting" certainly has nothing to do with this.

Comment: without node server reload updated data is not fetching.

Comment: How to make this clear. You need to actually "show your code" so that someone can tell you what you are doing incorrectly. Nothing to do with restarting. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try and have a look at this and see if it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57183568/mongodb-updates-not-showing-unless-i-restart-the-node-server/63613394#63613394